# Как узнать завершился ли процесс в AsyncTask?

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

После запуска приложение с помощью AsyncTask загружаю модель данных, затем передаю их адаптару, но дело в том, что данные не успеваю полностью загрузиться из ресурса. Выводиться в списке только 6 пунктов. 
Как сделать так, что бы адаптар заполнился только после того как AsyncTask  завершит полностью работу?

```
class CatTask extends AsyncTask<Void, Integer, Void> {
    // текст перед выполнением задачи
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();

    }
    // тяжолый код
    @Override
    protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
        // Получим массив строк из ресурсов
        try {
            .. тяжелый код

            }
        } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
    // сообщение после выполнения задачи
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        super.onPostExecute(result);

    }
}
```

Запускаю

```
CatTask catTask = new CatTask();
    catTask.execute();
```

Comment: Метод `onPostExecute` как раз для этого - он выполняется после завершения задачи.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Вам уже написали, что нужно смотреть в postExecute() но опишу поподробнее.
У AsynkTask'a в дженерик параметре(третий) для метода postExecute поставьте тип ваших данных (я так понимаю это что-то типа `List<MySuperData>` в итоге получите

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MySuperData> result) {
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Тут берете и сетите список в адаптер. В итоге адаптер получит сразу все данные

```
@Override
protected void onPostExecute(List<MySuperData> result) {
    mAdapter.setData(result)
    mAdapter.notifyDatasetChanged();
    super.onPostExecute(result);
}
```

Ну а этот result заполняется в `doInBackground`

```
 @Override
protected List<MySuperData> doInBackground(Void... params) {
    // Получим массив строк из ресурсов
    List<MySuperData> result = new ArrayList();
    try {
        //заполняем список

        }
    } catch (Resources.NotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Спасибо Вам!!! Все работает.

Answer (score 2):

Надо вызвать заполнение адаптера данными в `onPostExecute()`